# Seeking help with finding the general solution of this differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution of the following equation.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial f(x, t)} {\partial t} \sin(x \xi) \, dx =
\xi \int_0^\infty f(x, t) \cos(x \xi) \, dx -\alpha \xi ^2 t^{2 \alpha-1} \int_0^\infty f(x, t) \sin(x \xi) \, dx$$

I tried to introduce an additional $\xi \int_0^\infty f(x, t) \sin(x \xi) \, dx $ on both sides of the equation and then solving using method of characteristics but i was not able to find a general solution of $f(x,t)$.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using $$\xi\int_0^\infty f(x,t)\cos(x\xi)\,{\rm d}x = \int_0^\infty f(x,t)\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x\xi)\,{\rm d}x = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\sin(x\xi)\,{\rm d}x$$
the equation becomes $$\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \alpha\xi^2 t^{2\alpha-1}f\right]\sin(x\xi)\,{\rm d}x = 0$$

Comment: @Winther, Thank you very much for that.